# Выборка по дате

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Не могу понять как работает выборка по времени. Хочу сделать выборку данных с начала текущего дня, текущей недели, месяца и начала года, но результат мягко говоря не предсказуем - в выборку попадают старые записи с совсем не такой датой.

*Запрос на все записи за текущий день:*

```
        "SELECT %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q FROM '%q', '%q' WHERE %q >= DATE('now');"
```

*Запрос на все записи с начала текущей недели:*

```
            "SELECT %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q"
                 ", %q FROM '%q', '%q' WHERE %q >= DATE('now', 'weekday 1',);"
```

*С начала текущего месяца:*

```
        "SELECT %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q"
             ", %q FROM '%q', '%q' WHERE %q >= DATE('now', 'start of month');"
```

*С начала текущего года:*

```
              "SELECT %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q"
                   ", %q FROM '%q', '%q' WHERE %q >= DATE('now', 'start of year');"
```

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE DateField DETWEEN 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND 'yyyy-mm-dd'`

Comment: @AGS17, что вы имеете ввиду?как выбирать записи по промежутку времени как вы указали я знаю, и там все работает коректно.

Comment: для начала сделайте тестовые запросы без %q, что бы сам запрос как есть было видно. приведите пример данных и укажите что он выбирает сейчас и что из этого не правильно. И лучше текст запроса отправляемый в БД прямо из приложения сделайте, может оно подставляет вместо очередного параметра %q что нибудь неожиданное, например константу вместо поля